# How to select month and date from the popup datepicker in karate

Tags: karate

I'm working on a project to automate a mobile application using karate and appium. I'm able to select the very next/previous three months and next/previous three dates from the popup date picker using normal click(). E.g. I'm able to select the previous 3 months like Mar, Feb, and Jan w.r.t the current/default month(i.e. Apr) and was able to select the next three months May, June, and July w.r.t the current/default month(i.e. Apr). similarly I'm able to select the previous dates like 29, 28, and 27 w.r.t the current/default date(i.e. 30). Now I'm facing an issue when I try to select a month other than those 3 months and the same issue with the date too. It throws an error saying "Element could not be located"

FYI - In the dom I'm able to inspect all the month and date elements
I even tried with the following code, it isn't working it's failing to locate the element.

`And mouse().move('//XCUIElementTypeButton[@label="Apr"]', '//XCUIElementTypeButton[@label="Oct"]').go()`

Kindly correct me if I'm wrong, I doubt that since not all the months and dates are visible on the UI side, so they must be hidden and the tests are failing to locate those hidden elements.
Would like to request you to provide your inputs/opinion on this issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: agh another android question. I'll be honest, it may need some community contribution - so do consider doing it yourself or influencing people you know to do so. karate is very close and putting some efforts there would be worth it in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Typically iOS date picker can be handled in 2 ways

Both involve identifying each date picker wheel uniquely without a label (ie. locator shouldn't have date/month/year values)

**option 1:**

calling `input()` in karate and pass the value you want to select

```
* driver.input(<Locator>, "Oct")
```

**option 2:**

calling mobile command in appium via `script()` in karate

```
* def datePickerId = driver.elementId(<Locator>)
* def arguments = {"order": "next", "offset": 0.15, "element": "#(datePickerId)"}
* driver.script("mobile: selectPickerWheelValue", arguments)
```

refer : https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver#mobile-selectpickerwheelvalue

Comment: Option 1 - Will not work in my case as the locator I'm trying to use is Xpath i.e. 
//XCUIElementTypeButton[@label='Apr'], as you can see the month name comes attached to the Xpath, same goes for other month locators too.

Option 2 - I cannot locate element by id since the value is null for all of the months. it can be only accessed by Xpath as specified above. so do have something like driver.elementXpath(<Locator>)?
I've attached the inspector details for reference in the question section..

Comment: It should work with `//XCUIElementTypeButton[@label='Apr']` for both the option but i am afraid the locator will change every month, your dev team might have to add proper unique `identifier` for this element to make it accessible.